# Set image beside logo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new to Bootstrap. I need to set a logo beside a image. I tried but it did not show properly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="main-container">
             <div class="container">
                 <div class="section">
                
                        <img class="" src="img" >
                     
                    
                 </div>

             </div> 

         </div>
```

Comment: Just use your image as a background-image. Just see the example. https://jsfiddle.net/d2bjrw3L/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using bootstrap add the following classes to your parent element:  `d-flex align-items-center`, this will add a `display: flex` utility class and its `align-items-center` utility class to the parent.

See the following article at bootstrap for more info: [Flex - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="section d-flex align-items-center">

      <img class="" src="http://st.depositphotos.com/1029305/3546/v/170/depositphotos_35466099-Black-bird-icon.jpg">
      <h1>Intranotion</h1>


    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the illustration as a background image of the `.main-container` of `::before` pseudo element like this. The reason for choosing pseudo element is because it allows for greater control in terms of height and placehment.

```
.main-container {
    position: relative;
 }

.main-container::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    height: <height-of-image>;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(<image-path>);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change size and width of images accordingly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Image</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        .logo-area {
            max-height: 150px;
        }

            .logo-area .img1, .logo-area .img2 {
                max-height: 150px;
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section">
            <div class="logo-area">
                <img class="img1" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjPQa.png">
                <img class="img2" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbaTm.png">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```